# XLSX requiring password on MOSS 2007 Publishing Site (Public Site)

Tags: sharepoint-2007, xlsx, publishing-site

I have two documents, a **.docx** and an **.xlsx** both are in the same folder (Document Library) on the MOSS site and are linked in a content page. The .docx downloads as expected. When you click on the **.xlsx** file it **prompts** for a username/password.

The documents are both "Published" so that wasn't the issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment the xlsx extension from file **serverfilesExcelServer.xml** in location:

*C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\TEMPLATE\XML*

```
<ServerFiles>
 <Mapping FileExtension="odc"  RedirectUrlTemplate= "/_layouts/xlviewer.aspx?id=|0" NoGetRedirect="TRUE"/>
 <!--<Mapping FileExtension="xlsx" RedirectUrlTemplate= "/_layouts/xlviewer.aspx?id=|0" NoGetRedirect="TRUE"/>-->
 <Mapping FileExtension="xlsb" RedirectUrlTemplate= "/_layouts/xlviewer.aspx?id=|0" NoGetRedirect="TRUE"/>
</ServerFiles>
```

solution found here: [open email link to xlsx (excel 2007) file in MOSS 2007 document library.](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointcollaboration/thread/d7b0aa02-e9bf-492c-9311-47db4a895b77)